# command button action method not invoked

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I want to invoke a method from command button.
But it doesn't work and there's no anyone error's message.
How is this caused and how can I solve it?

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{contactMB.sendEmail()}"/>
```

```
public void sendEmail() {

    System.out.println("sendEmail method is invoked");

}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to include any relevant logs in `/var/log/maillog` or the Windows equivalent?

Comment: and don't use answers either!

Comment: @PauloHenriqueDutra Those don't appear to be mail logs, they appear to be servlet logs

Comment: "But in Java EE doesn't work and there's no anyone error's message" - Translated: when I call it in a completely different Java application that is deployed and run in an entirely different way, nothing happens. The easiest answer is at this point is: the method is actually never called. Did you try setting a breakpoint in that method or adding some logging to see that this method is ever actually invoked? I see primefaces in the logs, so this might just be a good old problem of a button not actually invoking the backing bean action method.

Comment: Indeed. Is the `sendEmail()` method itself called or not? If not, then this has **completely nothing** to do with sending a mail. You would have exactly the same problem when you replaced the entire method body by a single `System.out.println("Method invoked!");` line. Verify and confirm this so we can exclude a simple misinterpretation of the problem from being the cause.

Comment: Indeed. the method sendEmail() isn't even being called. I don't understand why

Comment: Because whatever should call it, has a problem. Its as simple as that, now you just need to figure out what it is and I can safely assume it is going to be something silly like not having a h:form or forgetting to make an action binding into a proper el with #{}. If you want help, edit your question and put in the relevant bits from the xhtml and the backing bean.

Comment: Thanks Gimby. I remade the xhtml code and it works, but I didn't find what was the problem. I've edited my question and put the code anyway. thanks for your support.